# Add an item to a combobox with code from a second form

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

My problem is very simple: i have a combobox in form1, i have a button that open form2 to write into a textbox the new item to add. Here my code:
Form1:

```
public static string new_item;
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Form2 f2= new Form2();
        f2.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Form2:

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1.new_item = textBox1.Text;
        combobox.Items.Add(new_item);
        this.Close();
    }
```

But the new item is not added to my comobobox.
I tried to refresh th combobox but i have the same result.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the item to your `ComboBox` after closing `Form2`:

```
public static string new_item;
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2= new Form2();
    f2.ShowDialog();
    comboBox1.Items.Add(new_item);  //this is missing in your code
}
```

---

But a better way would be creating a public property in Form2 to pass the string back:

```
public string Value { get; set; }

private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Value = textBox1.Text; //pass the TextBox value to the property
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; // Cancel would mean you closed/canceled the 
                                         // form without pressing OK-Button (btn1)
    this.Close();
}
```

Than in Form1 you can access the property and add the new item:

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2= new Form2();
    if(f2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) //check the result
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(f2.Value);//Add the new item
    }
}
```

Comment: You got a wrong line in `private void btn1_Click`:
`Form1.new_item = textBox1.Text;` should be `Value=textBox1.Text`

Comment: That's it Koopakiller, i puted this 'comboBox1.Items.Add(new_item);' in a wrong place.THank you it works!

Comment: can this item be added permenently? because when i close and rerun the app i must add it again.

Comment: @AhmedFantar Yes, you can save all items of the Combobox at `FormClosing`-event and restore them at loading. If you have any problem, you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming combo's name is `combobox`.

Form1:

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Form2 f2= new Form2();
    if (f2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
       combobox.Items.Add(f2.ItemValue);
}
```

Form2:

```
public string ItemValue {get {return textBox1.Text;} };

private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1.new_item = textBox1.Text;
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
```